# Changing Date Format on PDF Signature Stamp

Tags: pdf, itext, digital-signature, date-format

I can sign a pdf file, but the time format is too long.
I wabt to change Date format, but I couldnt..

Here is my code.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(input);
PdfStamper stp = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, output, '\0');
PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stp.SignatureAppearance;
**sap.SignDate = DateTime.Now;**
sap.SetCrypto(null, chain, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.WINCER_SIGNED);
sap.Reason = "Testování";
sap.Location = "Praha";
sap.Acro6Layers = true;
sap.Render = PdfSignatureAppearance.SignatureRender.GraphicAndDescription;
PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKMS, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_SHA1);
**dic.Date = new PdfDate(sap.SignDate);**
```

And, at the my pdf file, the signature stamp is like this:
"2012.11.01 05:21:00 +02:00"

but I want to like that: "01.11.2012 19:21:00"

Comment: Where is the date like that? In the visualization of the signature in the pdf or in some dialog of the pdf viewer? Please supply a sample.

Comment: date is in the pdf file, int the loft bottom corner.

Comment: there is a pdf signature in my pdf file, and the signature stamp is in the left bottom corner for each page. the date information is also in the signature stamp. But I couldnt change date fomat :(

Comment: You can customize the whole appearance in the file. I'll try and look up some sample later.

Comment: Thanks for answer mkl, I m waiting for you :)

Comment: Cf. Brunos answer, that's the text where I'd have looked for a sample...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go to http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures and read section 2.4 to find out how to create different signature appearances.